# The arm on my mesh won't connect

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

I'm a blender noobie and about to make my first animation. So I downloaded two models and started rigging one. I used Ctrl + J to join the

- -Arms
- -Head
- -Glasses
- -Legs
- -Chest
- -Eyes

I then parent the joined mesh to the armature I have but when I go into Pose mode and move, the arms disconnect from the mesh!

Any help is well appreciated

[This is the link to the .blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/id3lo5fqor6nj7t/US%20Support%20AND%20bf4%28cycles%29Armature%20.blend?dl=0)
[image: The arm wont attach]

Comment: Have you removed the duplicate vertices created by the joining of the meshes?

Comment: Removing doubled won't work easily here (I tried), even if this is generally better to have a continuous mesh. Try to tune the bones positions, parent with automatic weights and rework the weights painting them.

Comment: could you provide a .blend file to be able to have a look into your file?

Comment: 1)Thank you lemon I will try that
2) http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com I used this site to try and upload my file but it doesn't seem to work